# Problems encoding japanese characters in Excel5 output PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I'm using PHPExcel on a restricted server running PHP 5.6.

I have some Japanese characters that I'm trying to include in a CSV and Excel output. Seeing as there's potential to have the same output also in HTML or PDF I'm using PHPExcel to build all the data and just changing the writer depending on the request.

I've managed to get CSV export to open successfully in Excel by using `$objWriter->setUseBOM(true)` however exporting as an Excel file I'm getting the Japanese characters replaced with nonsense, such as:

```
Ã©ÂÂÃ¤Â¿Â¡Ã£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂÃ¯Â¼Â©Ã¯Â¼Â¤Ã£ÂÂ¡Ã£ÂÂ¼Ã£ÂÂ«Ã£ÂÂ«Ã¯Â¼Â©Ã¯Â¼Â¤Ã£ÂÂ®Ã¨Â¨ÂÃ¨Â¼ÂÃ£ÂÂÃ£ÂÂªÃ£ÂÂ
```

From what I've read my best bet is to convert the string to UTF-16LE, however, I don't have access to `mb_string` or `iconv` and I'm struggling to see how else I can solve this. I wondered whether Excel2007 would have the same issues, but I don't have access to `php_zip` or to `zlib` in order to use PCLZip. I think I'm screwed.

Does anyone have any idea how I can get Excel to correctly interpret these characters?

Comment: PHPExcel works purely with UTF-8; setting anything to UTF-16LE will not work

Comment: Fair enough, I must have misunderstood some of the other answers I've seen on SO. Some seem to suggest converting between UTF-8 and UTF-16LE and some also seem to suggest going the other way around (but those are all relating to CSV files and not Excel files).

Comment: Forgot to tag you @Mark, thanks for your clarification.
If I save the CSV as an XLS within Excel it's working fine. Also `PHPExcel_Shared_String::IsUTF8` says that my string is already UTF-8, so why would they be getting garbled? Is there some equivalent of the `$objWriter->setUseBOM(true)` that I need to use for Excel5?

Comment: There is no equivalent to use BOM for Excel5, because it's explicitly defined as UTF-8 and PHPExcel doesn't allow this to be changed. All conversion between UTF8 and BIFF8 Unicode  is handled internally

Comment: So why/how are my japanese characters getting garbled? There must be something I'm missing. Do you have any tips where I should look or what I should search for in Google to help me find the problem @MarkBaker? At some point the UTF-8 encoded string is ceasing to be UTF-8 or at least not _handled_ as UTF-8.

Comment: That I don't know for certain.... internally, the Excel5 Writer converts that UTF-8 to MS Excel's dual-byte BIFF8 encoding using `PHPExcel_Shared_String::UTF8toBIFF8UnicodeLong()`, which does require mb_string or iconv to be enabled, and can have problems with Asian phonetics

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145968/discussion-between-cyberneticiandave-and-mark-baker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem is the lack of `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` on the server. Without those, the encoding from UTF-8 to Biff8 (see `PHPExcel_Shared_String::UTF8toBIFF8UnicodeLong`) doesn't happen correctly.

In this case `PHPExcel_Shared_String::ConvertEncoding` simply returns the original character, which will not make sense in Biff8 - hence the issues experienced.

A standalone converter would need to be written, which is possible but is excessive for this particular situation where we can simply fall back to CSV. If anyone else gets this problem I would first check for the presence of `mb_convert_encoding` or `iconv` and, if possible, install those.